# Identity $i\int_0^{\pi}\left[\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{ix}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{-ix}\right)\right]dx=\frac{7}{3}\zeta(3) $

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, riemann-zeta

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367356/73025) and my partial answer to it. I've found that the proof of the 2nd identity reduces to showing that
$$i\int_0^{\pi}\left[\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{ix}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{-ix}\right)\right]dx=\frac{7}{3}\zeta(3) \tag{1}
$$
Here $\mathrm{Li}_2(z)$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) defined by analytic continuation of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ to the cut plane $\mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty)$ and $\zeta(3)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$ is the [Apéry's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html).

---

I am looking for a proof of $(1)$ or an alternative proof of the 2nd identity [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367356/73025). Thank you in advance.

Comment: As noted, *Monthy* problem 11654 solves this.  A solution will be published sometime this year, presumably.

Comment: The solutions mentioned above (Monthly 11654) can, for those that have access, be found on [JSTOR](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.06.549)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We give hints to show that

> $$i\int_0^\pi\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{ix}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{-ix}\right)dx=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{3}$$

in three steps.

> **First step.** We show that
>   $$
> I = i\int_0^\pi \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{ix}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{-ix}\right)dx = 4\int_0^1 \frac{\chi_2\left(\tfrac{t}{t+1}\right)}{t}\,dt,
> $$
>   where $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) and $\chi_2$ is the second order [Legendre chi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresChi-Function.html).

We need some previous knowledge. We use an [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.07.07.0003.01) of the dilogarithm:
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t\,z)}t\,dt.\tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$

After that we use [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify[Integrate[Log[a%20%2B%20b*Exp[I*c*x]]%2C%20x]%2C%20%20%20a%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20b%20%3E%200]) for all $a,b>0$:
$$
\int \ln\left(a+be^{\pm ix}\right)dx = x\ln(a) \pm i \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{be^{\pm ix}}{a}\right) + C. \tag{$\diamondsuit$}
$$

Now the solution of your integral problem:

\begin{align}
I &= i\int_0^\pi \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{ix}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-1-e^{-ix}\right)dx \\
&\stackrel{\spadesuit}{=} -i \int_0^\pi \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t} \left( \ln\left(1+t+te^{ix}\right) - \ln\left(1+t+te^{-ix}\right) \right)dt\,dx \\
&= -i \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t} \int_0^\pi \ln\left(1+t+te^{ix}\right) - \ln\left(1+t+te^{-ix}\right) dx\,dt.
\end{align}

By substitute $a=t+1$ and $b=t$ into $(\diamondsuit)$ we get:

\begin{align}
I &= -i \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t} \left[x\ln(t+1) + i\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{te^{ix}}{t+1}\right)\right]_0^\pi - \frac{1}{t}\left[x\ln(t+1) - i\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{te^{-ix}}{t+1}\right)\right]_0^\pi \,dt \\
&= -i \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t} \left( 2i\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{t}{t+1}\right) - 2i\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{t}{t+1}\right) \right) \, dt.
\end{align}

By using the fact, that $\chi_\nu(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{Li}_\nu(z) - \operatorname{Li}_\nu(-z)\right)$, we get:
$$
I = 4\int_0^1 \frac{\chi_2\left(\tfrac{t}{t+1}\right)}{t}\,dt.
$$

---

> **Second step.** We show that
>   \begin{align}
> I &= -2 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-2
>    \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)+2
>    \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-2
>    \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-2
>    \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln (3) \\ &+2
>    \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln (3)-2
>    \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \ln (3)+\frac{\ln
>   ^3(2)}{3}-\frac{2 \ln^3(3)}{3}+\ln^2(3) \ln
>    (2)+\frac{\pi^2}{3} \ln (2).
> \end{align}

To show this we have to calculate the following two integrals:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{t}{t+1}\right)}{t}\,dt &= \frac{5 \zeta (3)}{8},\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{t}{t+1}\right)}{t}\,dt &= \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)-
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \\
   &+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln
   (3)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln
   (3)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \ln (3)\\ &-\frac{\ln^3(2)}{6}+\frac{\ln^3(3)}{3}-\frac{1}{2} \ln (2)\ln^2(3)-\frac{1}{6} \pi^2 \ln (2) +\frac{5 \zeta (3)}{8}
\end{align}

By using the substitution $x=t/(t+1)$, and after that, by using $(\spadesuit)$ we get:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\pm \frac{t}{t+1}\right)}{t}\,dt = - \int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(\pm x)}{x(x-1)}\,dx = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 \mp tx)}{tx(x-1)}\,dt\,dx.
$$
I let the rest to the reader. *Mathematica* is able [to evaluate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[PolyLog[2%2C%20t%2F%28t%20%2B%201%29]%2Ft%2C%20%7Bt%2C%200%2C%201%7D]) both integrals.

---

> **Third step.** We show that
>   $$
>  I = \frac{7\zeta(3)}{3}.
> $$

To prove that
\begin{align}
& -2 \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-2
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)+2
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-2
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-2
   \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln (3) \\ &+2
   \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln (3)-2
   \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \ln (3)+\frac{\ln
  ^3(2)}{3}-\frac{2 \ln^3(3)}{3}+\ln^2(3) \ln
   (2)+\frac{\pi^2}{3} \ln (2)
\end{align}
equals to
$$
\frac{7\zeta(3)}{3},
$$
is quivalent to prove that
$$
2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln(3)+2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \ln(3)$$
equals to
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3}\ln(2)+\frac{1}{3}\ln^3(2)-\frac{1}{3} \ln^2(3) \ln\left(\frac{27}{8}\right)-\frac{\zeta(3)}{6}.
$$
This work is done by [you](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451635/153012), so eventually you've answered your own question.